# How do I get into this dict in json?

Tags: json, python-3.x

How do I get into roomInfo in this json? It's a snippet of a very long json.

EDIT:
I have updated the json with a full part of a "section".

```
{
    "code":0,
    "data":[
        {
            "createTime":1578399707995,
            "dynamicCommentNum":0,
            "dynamicContent":"",
            "dynamicId":32191,
            "dynamicImgList":[
                {
                    "height":520,                       
                    "width":458
                }
            ],
            "dynamicPraiseNum":5,               
            "isPraise":0,               
            "memberId":2663481,             
            "position":"",              
            "region":6,
            "rongCloudId":"PROD_ROOMNO:3412872",
            "roomInfo":{
                "roomId":2827296,
                "roomNo":3412872,
                "roomOwnerId":2663481
            }
        },
```

I've tried many different ways, but none seems to work. For example:

```
for p in dynamic_data['data']['roomInfo'][0]:
    print('UserID: ' + str(p['roomNo']))
    print('MemberID: ' + str(p['roomOwnerId']))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This is the main dictionary
|   These are first level keys
|   |  These are the values of the first level keys
v   |       |  A dictionary inside the first level `data` key.
{   v       v    |  Key inside the list that's inside the `data` key.
    "code": 0,   |  |
    "data": [ <--|--|------ This value is a list inside the `data` key.
        {  <-----'  v
            "roomInfo":{
                "roomNo":3412872,
                "roomOwnerId":2663481,                  
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So the code should be:

```
#      Main dictionary
#            |  Get content of data object (a list)
#            |          |  Get the value "roomInfo" from each dict
#            v          v       |       Take the attribute from it
for p in dynamic_data['data']:  v           v
    print('UserID: ' + str(p['roomInfo']['roomNo']))
    print('MemberID: ' + str(p['roomInfo']['roomOwnerId']))
```

Comment: I have updated the post with a more "full" version of the json.

Comment: Ah, I see ['roomInfo'] does not exist in all the lists inside ['data']. I guess that is why I get that key error.